# iOS reverse geocoding issue not returning value for placemark.locality

Tags: ios, iphone, geocoding

I encountered a very odd issue when I use CLGeocoder to get current city name.
The place I'm using to verify this is Cupertino. I am 100% sure it's not a coverage issue.

The NSLog printed the placemark correctly, but when it came to placemark.locality, then
it printed (null). I tried other properties and they all work. I look around and people seem to have similar problems, but no there are no feasible answers. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

The code is below:

```
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation
                       completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {  

                           NSLog(@"%@",placemarks);

                           CLPlacemark *placemark =[placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                           NSLog(@"%@",placemark);
                           NSString *city = placemark.locality;
                           NSLog(@"City：%@", city);
                           if (!city){
                              city = placemark.subAdministrativeArea;
                           }
                           NSLog(@"City：%@", city);
```

Comment: what iOS version are you targeting?

Comment: target for versions after iOS 4.3, all failed.BTW, I am currently building with 6.1 SDK, will this be an issue?

Comment: locality is only available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: tried iOS6.0, didn't work

Comment: Just got rejected from App Store, said that location wasn't found when launched app. I was displaying placemark.locality, and I'm guessing the tester could have been in Cupertino. I'm going to use placemark.name as backup if locality is null.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try this,

```
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            for (CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks) {
                NSString *city = [placemark locality];
                NSLog(@"%@", city);
            }
}
```